# What makes change view in my uploadImage()?

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, firebase-storage

If I change a new image in my EditActivity, the changed image will be reflected, but it will be taken to the start screen of the app before pressing the save button. I do not see any special error when I look at logcat, but I want to know what caused it.

**This is EditProfileActivity Source**

after work uploadImage method soon view go home... but changed image reflected

```
 private void updateProfile(String fullname, String username, String bio) {

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("fullname", fullname);
        hashMap.put("username", username);
        hashMap.put("bio", bio);

        reference.updateChildren(hashMap);

    }


    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri){

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));

    }


    private void uploadImage(){
        // Progress .xml에서 Visible 하는거 구현
        final ProgressBar pd = new ProgressBar(this);
        pd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         //To show ProgressBar


        if (mImageUri != null){
            final StorageReference filereference = storageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    +"."+getFileExtension(mImageUri));

            uploadTask = filereference.putFile(mImageUri);

            uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
                @Override
                public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }

                    return filereference.getDownloadUrl();
                }

            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        String myUrl = downloadUri.toString();

                        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());


                        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("imageurl", ""+myUrl);

                        reference.updateChildren(hashMap);
                        pd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                    } else {
                        showMessage("Failed");
                    }
                }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    showMessage(e.getMessage());
                }
            });

        }else {
            showMessage("이미지를 선택해주세요");
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            mImageUri = result.getUri();

            uploadImage();

        }else {
            showMessage("무엇인가 잘못되었습니다.");
        }
    }

    private void showMessage(String text) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

**This is my HomeActivity**

```
package com.example.together.Activities;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.together.Fragment.SearchFragment;
import com.example.together.Fragment.HomeFragment;
import com.example.together.Fragment.NotificationFragment;
import com.example.together.Fragment.ProfileFragment;
import com.example.together.R;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    Fragment seletedFragment = null;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);

        Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (intent != null){
            String publisher = intent.getString("publisherid");

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("profileid", publisher);
            editor.apply();

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ProfileFragment()).commit();

        } else{

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();

        }

    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.nav_bottomBar_home:
                            seletedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;

                        case R.id.nav_bottomBar_search:
                            seletedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                            break;

                        case R.id.nav_bottomBar_notification:
                            seletedFragment = new NotificationFragment();
                            break;


                        case R.id.nav_bottomBar_profile:
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putString("profileid", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                            editor.apply();
                            seletedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                            break;


                    }

                    if (seletedFragment != null){
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, seletedFragment).commit();
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            };


}
```

What makes it's changing the screen?
even though there is no intent to go to HomeActivity...

Comment: Can you be more clear about your issue? When is the app redirected to Home page? After you click the save button? or just before you set the image? some time after you set the image (but automatically)? before or after sending it to firebase?

Comment: After i set the image, after i choose image and crop even though i didn't click save the button it's show me ActivityEdit and soon automatically go to HomeActivity